# What to do to Join a Trello Board after an Invite?

Tags: trello

I have sent out invitations to my Trello board, what do I need to do when they arrive at the board, to then join it?

Answer (score 1):

If you sent out the invitations to the board, you don't have to do anything.

When the users you invited sign up, they will have an open invitation to join your board and will just need to click 'Join Board'.